# c# Ftp.UploadFile

Tags: c#

I am trying to improve working code seeing if there was any potential issues or performance problems. This code will connect to an ftp server and upload a file.

```
public  SendFiles(string demoFileLocation, string liveFileLocation, string fileName, string username, string password)
        {
            ResultStatus resultStatus = new ResultStatus();
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(demoFileLocation, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(liveFileLocation, fileName);
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(demoFileLocation))
            {
                resultStatus.ResultType = Result.Code.Error;
                resultStatus.Message = "Files cannot be located";
                return resultStatus;
            }
            else
            {

                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destFile);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username.Normalize(), password.Normalize());
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(sourceFile);
                request.ContentLength = file.Length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
                int bytes = 0;
                int total_bytes = (int)file.Length;
                FileStream fileStream = file.OpenRead();
                Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                while (total_bytes > 0)
                {
                    bytes = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    total_bytes = total_bytes - bytes;
                }
                fileStream.Close();
                stream.Close();
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();
                return resultStatus;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(demoFileLocation, fileName);
> string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(liveFileLocation, fileName);
> if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(demoFileLocation))
> {
>     resultStatus.ResultType = Result.Code.Error;
>     resultStatus.Message = "Files cannot be located";
>     return resultStatus;
> }
> ```

- It would be better to check wether `sourceFile` exists than checking if the directory exists.
- Sometimes it may be a good thing to have a `else` but usually it is not needed if you `return` inside the `if`.

  ---

Inside the `else` you have

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
```

which initialise the `buffer` to contain `4097` bytes acessible from `[0]..[4096`. It would be better performance wise to have `new byte [4096]`

---

Both streams

> ```
> FileStream fileStream = file.OpenRead();
> Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
> ```

are implenting the `IDisposable` interface. Therefor you should enclose them inside a `using` block to properly dispose and closing them. Having them inside a `using` block will dispose them as well if there is an exception beeing thrown.

---

> ```
> FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
> response.Close();
> ```

This doesn't buy you anything because you aren't using it. You can remove it without problem.

---